# Unable to detect checkbox state

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, .net-1.1, asp.net-1.1

Anyone know why the following always gives me a `0` even if `cbEligibleToJoin` is `Checked`?

```
if (cbEligibleToJoin.Checked = 1) then
    objSQLCommand.Parameters.Add("@eligible_to_join", SqlDbType.Int, 4).Value = ctype(1, integer)
else
    objSQLCommand.Parameters.Add("@eligible_to_join", SqlDbType.Int, 4).Value = ctype(0, integer)
end if
```

I tried `if (cbEligibleToJoin.Checked = 1) then` and `if (cbEligibleToJoin.Checked) then` and get the same result, i.e. `0` in the db.

Comment: should you not be checking for True/False ?

Comment: I thought if I don't include the `= 1` it checks for `true` or `false`?

Comment: where have you written this code?on button click or any post back event?have you checked IsPostBack property in page load?

Comment: @SQLGuru, Just tried `= true` and it makes no difference.

Comment: @AmolKolekar, it's in a button `onclick`.  If it's inserting `0`'s into the database, doesn't that mean the button is working?

Comment: take a look at mt proposed solution below

Comment: but have you checked IspOstback event in PageLoad?If not then it must be resetting all states of the controls..please check that first...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your issue is that the checkbox value is looking for a boolean of 'true' or 'false', not an integer

Using the elseif will determine if it is actually going into one of these

```
If cbEligibleToJoin.Checked = True Then
     objSQLCommand.Parameters.Add("@eligible_to_join", SqlDbType.Int, 4).Value = 1
ElseIf cbEligibleToJoin.Checked = False Then
    objSQLCommand.Parameters.Add("@eligible_to_join", SqlDbType.Int, 4).Value = 0
End If
```

Comment: I've just tried `if (cbEligibleToJoin.Checked = true) then` and it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Is the page posting back and actually setting the control to checked once it has been clicked?

Comment: When the control is checked, no postback happens.  Post back currently  happens when the button is clicked.

Comment: I've just replicated the checkbox and button, works fine for me. I did it with your if and it didnt work. Replaced the 1 with 'true', and got rid of the brackets and now it functions fine

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
if (cbEligibleToJoin.Checked) then
    objSQLCommand.Parameters.Add("@eligible_to_join", SqlDbType.Int, 4).Value = 1
else
    objSQLCommand.Parameters.Add("@eligible_to_join", SqlDbType.Int, 4).Value = 0
end if
```